# Refresh failed with a 403 Forbidden error. The refresh token was revoked or expired. - When tried to enable Refreshtoken on Xamarin-Android project

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am receiving "Refresh failed with a 403 Forbidden error. The refresh token was revoked or expired." when i tried to enable the refreshtokens on Azure mobile app with AD authentication, app is build in Android(Xamarin) with client authentication flow implemented. I am doubting if refreshtokens are meant for client authentication flow, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have issue with one of the Google account.
The others accounts do not have problem.
I notice the different is on the account with Two steps authentication enabled, the forbidden error is returned.
Please check it in your case.

Updated: it is not related to 2-step authentication.
Please check the detail here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/293